# How to set allow_null=True for all ModelSerializer fields in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a ModelSerializer . I want to set allow_null=True for all of the fields of the serializer . But I don't want to do it manually, I mean- I don't want to write allow_null=True for every field . Is there any shortcut? Is there anything like read_only_fields=() ?

**This is my Serializer**

```
class ProductPublicListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    minimum_price = serializers.FloatField(source='min_product_price', allow_null=True)
    maximum_price = serializers.FloatField(source='max_product_price', allow_null=True)
    # rating = serializers.FloatField(source='productreview__rating', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'featured_image', 'minimum_price', 'maximum_price', 'total_review',                 'average_rating')
       read_only_fields = ('name', 'featured_image', 'minimum_price', 'total_review')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve it by overriding `get_fields` in your `ModelSerializer` class, so:

```
class ProductPublicListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = dict(super().get_fields())
        for field_name, field_class in fields.items():
            field_class.allow_null = True
        return fields
```